# initialize callback function after prevent default

Tags: javascript, function, callback, addeventlistener

i have a submit event, where i check the inputs upon clicking the submit button.
and then i have a seperate function, that needs to be triggered after the inputs have been checked the
value has to be sent to the server (Post request).

how can i achieve that? is a callback the right approach?
i tried calling the function with checkinputs(sendFeedback).

here's the code:

```
//all the form fields saved as variables
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const btn = document.getElementById("sendButton");


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkInputs();
  
});

function checkInputs() {
  //get Values from the inputs
  const nameValue = name.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const textValue = text.value.trim();




  if (nameValue === "") {
    //showerror
    //add error class

    setErrorFor(name, "Please fill out your name");


  }
  else if (!onlyLettersInName(nameValue)) {
    setErrorFor(name, "Only letters are allowed");
  }

  else {
    //add success class
    setSuccessFor(name);
  }
  if (emailValue === "") {
    setErrorFor(email, "Please fill out your e-mail");
  }
  else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
    setErrorFor(email, "E-mail is not valid");
  }
  else {
    //add success class
    setSuccessFor(email);
  }
  if (textValue.length <= 50) {
    setErrorFor(text, "Please enter at least 50 characters");
  }
  else {
    setSuccessFor(text);    

  }

  

}





   
function sendFeedback() {
  const xhrFeedback = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhrFeedback.open("POST", "http://SOMEURL.com", true);


  xhrFeedback.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhrFeedback.readyState === 4 && xhrFeedback.status === 201) {
      console.log(xhrFeedback.status)
      alert("sent!")
    }
    if (xhrPizzaOrder.readyState === 4 && xhrPizzaOrder.status > 300) {
      console.log("Bad Request");
    }
  }

  xhrFeedback.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "MYTOKEN");
  xhrFeedback.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  xhrFeedback.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
};
```

Comment: Your `sendFeedback` function is supposed to be a Promise. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: i can't pass the function sendFeedback as a callback to the checkInputs function? i tried that with making the checkInputs function accept a callback as an argument:
function checkInputs(callback)...

Comment: the reason behind adding it as a callback is the case where this behavior can change. e.g. if you will have `checkInputs` function called from different places, that would require different action based on some condition. But if `checkInputs` will always `sendFeedback` in the end, then callback is not necessary. Just call your function where you need it.

Comment: i see. thanks for the clarification. i got it to work with just calling the functions sequentially.